# Unable to view certain website

Tags: firefox, ftp, connection, filezilla

I can't connect to some websites at my work place, but I am able to connect to the websites outside of work. Firefox shows an error like this:

> The connection has timed out
>   The server at www.examplewebsite.com is taking too long to respond.
>   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments. If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection. If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

I have tried to fix the problem by:

- Clearing the cache
- Check the firewall, and I have even turned off the firewall
- I used `ping` and `tracert`, but both only show `REQUEST TIMED OUT` and `100% DATA LOSS`

Am I being blocked from viewing these websites at work? I have some access on some website and I can't log in using ftp/filezilla either.

Comment: "I have some access on some website", what? I'd just suggest to ask your network administrator.

Comment: What website are you talking about? Does anymone else have those problems with it?

Comment: @Michael K yes, all in the office can't access anymore certain websites that we are monitoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could tell if your network administrator is blocking access or if the website is down for everyone is this site:

http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

But you could just ask your network admin.

Comment: It is just me, we have already contact the network admin it seems to normally  fine, he's not blocking us. but still we cannot connect.

Comment: If you cannot even ping the host and the network administrator is not blocking access, then it is likely a problem with your network configuration at work or your [HOSTS file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) has some strange settings.

Comment: Where would I start checking my network configuration?

Comment: I would suggest letting your network department/administrators look into that, because they know their infrastructure best and it is their job.